# Should I ask a question of which I know the answer is in a different post to a different question?

Tags: discussion

I recently wanted to ask the question: How does the menthol in shower gel give a cool sensation?

While doing my standard check for already asked questions I found this question: [Why does menthol (e.g. peppermint) feel cool to the tongue?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/558). I believe that the ANSWER to that question is the same as the answer to mine, even though the question is different (but clearly related).

My question is: should I still ask my question or should I refrain from doing that?

The reason I'm asking is that although I already know the answer now, others who come looking with the same question as I had might not find the already answered question, because it doesn't ask the same question.

Comment: I'd wait for an administrator to answer your question before posting (as I'm not one).  HOWEVER, I have seen this type of thing encouraged in other communities on SE.  I think that a question's usefulness generally is more important than how 'tacky' it may end up seeing when an individual posts Qs and corresponding As.

Comment: @LordStryker no need to wait for a mod or whatever, feel free to experiment with stuff like this, if it's not something good we can always revert it later :)

Answer (score 4):

(Sorry for the delay, I thought that I had replied to this one)

I don't think it's a bad thing to do this, though it does lead to some level of duplication. If you wish, feel free to self answer the question with some situation-specific (i.e., not applying to the other one) text in your answer.

One other option is to edit the other question so that it reflects both possible questions.